# Possible conflict with Ender's Game and Earth Unaware

Tags: enders-game, orson-scott-card

I could be wrong, it's been a while since I read Ender's Game completely, but didn't they say that we first knew of the Formics because of an attack on a family miner's ship? This is covered in Earth Unaware but they blast the Italians ships to bits and I remember that in Ender's Game they show the first attack in a video as the Formics slaughtering them unaware of being recorded(as they had no need for recording)?

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! :) If you make that an answer I'll upvote it

Comment: To be fair, it's not that hard to fit anyway - the first thing Earth has heard was basically "There's aliens out there, and they destroyed a whole free-miner family without provocation!". The prequels had plenty of opportunities for the kinds of recordings mentioned in Ender's Game - arguably, the book is talking about the first *invasion*, not the first literal attack (though Himarm is absolutely right in that Card made several changes to allow the universe to grow over time).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

enders game just brushed on the beginnings of meeting the formics, anything said in Enders game, but then doesn't quite fit in newer books are simply because card is elaborating in the newer books. And from what I've read, *Ender's Game* actually has newer editions now that fix some of these issues. Something simple like instead of the first time we meet the Formics to one of the first times, fixes simple little discrepancies like that.

This (discrepancy resolution idea) is covered in detail here: [What is Orson Scott Card's position on discrepancies between various Enderverse books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109101/what-is-orson-scott-cards-position-on-discrepancies-between-various-enderverse)

Comment: I'm sorry man, I'm new here so I don't have the necessary reputation to upvote you :/

Comment: Although Ender's Game has had planned new editions for a while now, the last version published was from 1991.